# TeXstudio slow to start up and crashes when I press ctrl+f

Tags: texstudio

Immediately after startup TeXstudio does not respond for a very long time. Then when it runs, it works fine as always (any input runs, compiling goes great etc), except that when I press ctrl + f, it again does not respond for a very long time (15+ mins).

I have uninstalled and reinstalled TeXstudio several times, but the problem always persists.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be?

Edit: I have Windows 10, 64 bit. My TeXstudio version is 4.3.1, so I assume it's the latest version and it's appropriate for my system.

Comment: What is your configuration? Operating system? What version of Texstudio  have you installed? Have you installed the right version 32bit or 64bit for your pc?

Comment: Miltos: I updated the question with the relevant info. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Unistall the texstudio for now and then be sure to delete the texstudio folders in C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming and in C:\Program Files. Then restart your computer. Then follow the link: https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/releases/download/4.3.1/texstudio-4.3.1-win-qt6.exe to download the 4.3.1, Qt6, 64bit version of TeXstudio and install it again. If the problem persists that means that something in your configuration conflicts with texstudio maybe an antivirus?

Comment: Ok, I'll do that later in the day. (TeXstudio is running well right now and I'd like to take advantage of that.) I'll come back to you though! Thanks, Miltos!

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem persists :(

Comment: Have you tried any other TeX editors? Are they running smoothly? Also try an other version of TexStudio e.g Qt5 version or even an older version as 4.2.3?

Comment: One more thought: do you keep your windows 10 updated?

Comment: I have the same experience. Very weird. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: No I haven't. The problem ist still there, even though my windows is up to date and everything :(